# Laravel Nginx passsing data to views

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

Im passing data to a view:

```
$player_data = DB::connection('a3db')->select('SELECT * FROM players WHERE playerid = ?', [$pid]);
$skills = decodelicense($player_data['0']->skill);
$civ_licenses = decodelicense($player_data['0']->civ_licenses);
$med_licenses = decodelicense($player_data['0']->med_licenses);
$cop_licenses = decodelicense($player_data['0']->cop_licenses);
$adac_licenses = decodelicense($player_data['0']->adac_licenses);
return view('players.ajax', ['data' => $player_data,'pid' => $pid,'civ_licenses' => $civ_licenses,'cop_licenses' => $cop_licenses,'adac_licenses' => $adac_licenses,'med_licenses' => $med_licenses,'skills' => $skills]);
```

This is causing undefined variable errors using nginx on our webserver but working fine in my local testing enviroment.

Im running Laravel 5.2, Nginx 1.2.1 and PHP 5.5.33-1~dotdeb+7.1

Error:

Next exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: civ_licenses (View: /usr/share/nginx/www/husky/resources/views/players/player.blade.php)' in /usr/share/nginx/www/husky/storage/framework/views/2eaefa36b185667c6ab8fa106c6757a738f3e48b.php:157

Full Stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/raw/pndXegtE

```
                  <div id="licenseciv">
                      <div class="well">
                        @if ($civ_licenses[0] != '"[]"')
                          @for ($x = 0; $x < count($civ_licenses); $x=$x+2)
                            @if ($civ_licenses[$x+1] == "1")
                              <button  type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-sm' style='margin-right:2px;margin-bottom:4px;font-size: 15px;' onclick="license('{{$civ_licenses[$x]}}','civ')" >{{querylicensename($civ_licenses[$x])}}</button>
                            @else
                              <button  type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' style='margin-right:2px;margin-bottom:4px;font-size: 15px;' onclick="license('{{$civ_licenses[$x]}}','civ')" >{{querylicensename($civ_licenses[$x])}}</button>
                            @endif
                          @endfor
                        @endif
                      </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: Post full error message.

Comment: Which variable is undefined?

Comment: Added it to the question

Comment: Source code of the blade will be helpful as well.

Comment: Added the first and only occurence aswell

Comment: a couple of things have you cleared your view cache etc , also is the variable `civ_licenses` being used within a partial thats included within another, as you need to pass that into the  view @include('view..., ['civ_licenses',$civ_licenses]); etc

Comment: It is highly unlikely that the difference is caused by Nginx. For the future consider changing your development environment to [Laravel Homestead](https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead). For now clear your cache using `php artisan cache:clear`. Please post the content of the view and its includes (and be sure to label them).